# ¿Hay alguna otra manera de automatizar word desde c#, sin utilizar marcadores?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hice una forma que es con los marcadores, hasta el momento me esta funcionando correctamente. Estoy pensando que con el paso de tiempo que los marcadores los puede eliminar el usuario por accidente. para ello utilice Microsoft.Office.Interop

Answer (score -1):

Sí, hay otra manera. Es mediante el método de buscar y reemplazar, en donde buscas el texto que se quiere reemplazar.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algunos ejemplos para que la respuesta esté completa?